# Using Webpack with Vue to access git version number does not work

Tags: vue.js, webpack

My `vue.config.js` looks like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { GitRevisionPlugin } = require('git-revision-webpack-plugin');
const gitRevisionPlugin = new GitRevisionPlugin();

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      gitRevisionPlugin,
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          VERSION: JSON.stringify(gitRevisionPlugin.version()),
          COMMITHASH: JSON.stringify(gitRevisionPlugin.commithash()),
          BRANCH: JSON.stringify(gitRevisionPlugin.branch()),
      }),
    ],
  }
};
```

in my `App.vue` file I try to access VERSION by

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { shallowRef, ref } from 'vue';

const version = ref(VERSION);
</script>
```

however, that does not work. I though this is because VERSION is only available in after build, but supressing the error does not work. I tried adding this to the `.eslintrc` file

```
    "globals": {
    "VERSION": "readonly",
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "does not work" isn't a clear explanation of the problem. How exactly this does not work and how is eslintrc supposed to help?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).